# Mostrar PDF con estilos propios con wkHTMLtoPDF en c# ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf

Instale [wkHTMLtoPDF](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/) y puedo mostrar el PDF, pero no puedo mostrar mis estilos personalizados y mis scripts. Probé con el siguiente código(lo use también para otras vistas):

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/recibo.css")
```

y

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/scripts-recibo.css")
```

Comment: Has intentado no utilizar la renderización de MVC, intenta poner la ruta completa de los archivos css ya que tal vez la librería no compile este tipo de referencias.

Comment: Trate poniendo las rutas absolutas, desde C: pero tampoco puedo y no encuentro la forma. El pdf queda bien excepto por eso. No logro que me tome ni los estilos ni el código de javascript.

Comment: Puedes compartir un poco más del código y las configuraciones que estas utilizando. Y el resultado que te genera para asi poder ayudarte de una mejor manera.